# How to access property of an object that was retrieved from database?

Tags: php, json, object

How can I use the .(dot) notation in accessing my object that came from my database?

I saved my file like this.

```
 Database:

 account_text  | value 
 Cash on Hand  | {"debit":2110675.79,"credit":0}
```

Now when I echoed out this to my page:

```
 <td><?php echo $data->account_text; ?></td>
 <td><?php $data->value; ?></td>
```

I get this result:

```
Front View HTML TABLE
   Cash on Hand |  {"debit":2110675.79,"credit":0}
```

When I tried using:

```
$data->value.debit 

:I get a Use of undefined constant debit
```

Also I tried using:

```
 $data->value->debit

 :Trying to get property of non-object
```

Can anyone give me any idea on how to solve this please?

Comment: maybe `echo json_decode($data->value)->debit;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$data->value` is a string representing a JSON object. You have to convert it to object.

```
$data->value = json_decode($data->value);
echo $data->value->debit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to access it like $data->value["debit"]